# Mocking Functions that take keyword Arguments in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to unit test a Discord bot. However, my test keeps failing with:

> send() takes no keyword arguments.

The function works just fine in practice, and the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20send#discord.TextChannel.send) do specify the keyword arguments.
How can I make this work?

Test:

```py
@patch('cogs.events.MuteRecord')
async def test_member_join(self, mockMuteRecord): # Tests the on_member_join event, makes sure muted joining are muted and that the embed is sent

    with self.subTest(): # Tests a normal, unmuted, non-new account joining
        member = AsyncMock()
        member.created_at = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8))
        mockMuteRecord.checkIfMuted = AsyncMock(return_value=False)
        channel = AsyncMock()
        channel.send = AsyncMock(spec=discord.TextChannel.send)
        fakeSelf = AsyncMock(bot = AsyncMock(get_guild = PropertyMock(spec = discord.TextChannel,return_value=channel)))
        await Events.on_member_join(fakeSelf, member)
        member.send.assert_called_once_with("Welcome to the xyz Discord! You can DM me ++verify for instruction on how you can verify!")
```

Failing code being tested:

```py
try:

        await member.send("Welcome to the xyz Discord! You can DM me ++verify for instruction on how you can verify!")
    except:
        BOT_LOG.debug(f"Unable to DM new member {member.id}")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="User joined the server", description=f"{member.mention}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    if (datetime.now() - member.created_at).days <= 7:
        embed.add_field(name="Warning", value="New Account", inline=False)
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(server)
    await guild.get_channel(joined_left_channel).send(embed=embed)
    BOT_LOG.debug(f"Checking if {member.display_name} is muted")
    needs_muting = await MuteRecord.checkIfMuted(self, member)

    if needs_muting:
        BOT_LOG.debug(f"New Join {member.display_name} should be muted; assigning muted role")
        muted_role = guild.get_role(Muted)
        await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    else:
        BOT_LOG.debug(f"New Join {member.display_name} is not muted.")
```

Comment: `channel.send = AsyncMock(spec=discord.TextChannel.send)` <-- Are you sure this is what you're supposed to be doing with the `send` property? Why is this needed?

Comment: Actually nvm, I see that you're mocking the method